# Error while installing Ruby 1.9.3 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I already have ruby-2.0.0-p0

And I am trying to install Ruby 1.9.3

```
rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p448
```

Facing following error

```
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.

No binary rubies available for: ubuntu/12.04/i386/ruby-1.9.3-p448.

Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.

Checking requirements for ubuntu.

Requirements installation successful.

Installing Ruby from source to: /home/icicle/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...

ruby-1.9.3-p448 - #downloading ruby-1.9.3-p448, this may take a while depending on your connection...

curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'www.dnsbalance.ring.gr.jp'

There was an error(6).

Checking fallback: http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.9/ruby-1.9.3-p448.tar.bz2

Checking fallback: http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.9/ruby-1.9.3-p448.tar.bz2

No fallback URL could be found, try increasing timeout with:


    echo "export rvm_max_time_flag=20" >> ~/.rvmrc


There has been an error fetching the ruby interpreter. Halting the installation.
```

Comment: Appears to be a network / DNS resolution issue - can you ping any of the addresses above?

Answer (score -1):

try to do this things:

- `ping ftp.ruby-lang.org`
- `rvm reload`.
- `sudo /etc/init.d network restart`

Maybe it helps you understand where is problem.

You always can uninstall 2.0.0 and install 1.9.3 and 2.0.0 again
or reinstall rvm ( but it's not good way )

:)

Comment: can you write you output of "rvm -v" and "rvm list" command ?

Comment: do you run "echo "export rvm_max_time_flag=20" >> ~/.rvmrc" ?